# error: control reaches end of non-void function:(

Tags: c, recursion, return

I know this has been asked before but still I couldn't find a fix. The program is supposed to sum all even digits in a number using recursion. Here's the code that produces the error `control reaches end of non-void function`:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int sum_even_d(unsigned long n);

int main()
{
    unsigned long n;
    int x;
    printf("Enter n : \n");
    scanf("%lu",&n);
    x=sum_even_d(n);
    printf("%d\n",x);
    return 0;

}

int sum_even_d(unsigned long n)
{
    if(n==0) return 0;
    if(n%2==0)
        return (sum_even_d(n/10)+n%10);//*error here*//
}
```

If I add one line though, the program works perfectly. I don't understand what made the difference:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int sum_even_d(unsigned long n);

int main()
{
    unsigned long n;
    int x;
    printf("Enter n : \n");
    scanf("%lu",&n);
    x=sum_even_d(n);
    printf("%d\n",x);
    return 0;

    }

int sum_even_d(unsigned long n)
{
    if(n==0) return 0;
    if(n%2==0)
        return (sum_even_d(n/10)+n%10);
    else return (sum_even_d(n/10));//*added this*//
}
```

Comment: If you don't return anything from a function declared to return something, then you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: The return value isn't decided when `n%2==1` .

Comment: What do you want the function to do when say `n=3`

Comment: It does not matter the dup is C++; it would be the same in any other similar programming language

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, any odd number will cause the program to fall off the bottom of the function without a `return`.  The declared type, `int`, requires a return value.  When you added an `else` clause with a return value, you covered the remaining case with a value.

Comment: got it. thanks alot everyone!

Comment: The same happens to a negative odd value, why specify *positive*?

Comment: Good point ... fixing ...

Answer (score 1):

In the first snippet when `n` is odd, the function `sum_even_d` won't reach any `return` statement. But since the function is defined a non-void, it must return a value. This is what the compiler is telling you. In the second snippet your `else` statement is taking care of this code path.

Answer (score 0):

All possible paths of a function that do not have a return type of `void` **must** return a value.

In your first piece of code, if the condition `if(n%2==0)` is false, the code runs to the end of the function but hasn't returned a value.  Back in the calling function, the return value is unknown because you didn't specify one.  This invoked undefined behavior.

Your second code does return a value for all paths, so no error.